# Compilation fails for JDK 11 and compiles fine for JDK 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

The code compiles fine with JDK 8 (1.8.0_212) but fails to compile using JDK 11 (11.0.3) both Oracle jdk and open jdk (aws corretto)

Tried compiling using javac and with Maven (maven version 3.6.1 and maven-compiler-plugin  version 3.8.0) it compiles for JDK 8 and fails for JDK 11.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class AppDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // NO error here
        giveMeStream("http://foo.com").map(wrap(url -> new URL(url)));

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("http://foo.com/, http://bar.com/");
        // error: unreported exception MalformedURLException;
        // must be caught or declared to be thrown
        list.stream().flatMap(
            urls -> Arrays.<String>stream(urls.split(",")).map(wrap(url -> new URL(url)))
        );

        // error: unreported exception MalformedURLException;
        // must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Stream.concat(
            giveMeStream("http://foo.com").map(wrap(url -> new URL(url))),
            giveMeStream("http://bar.com").map(wrap(url -> new URL(url))));

    }


    static Stream<String> giveMeStream(String s) {
        return Arrays.stream(new String[]{s});
    }

    static <T, R, E extends Throwable> Function<T, R>
    wrap(FunException<T, R, E> fn) {
        return t -> {
            try {
                return fn.apply(t);
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
            }
        };
    }

    interface FunException<T, R, E extends Throwable> {
        R apply(T t) throws E;
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Expected : No compilation error
Actual : compilation error for JDK11
Error message with JDK 11:

s.<String>stream(urls.split(",")).map(wrap(url -> new URL(url)))
                                                               ^
AppDemo.java:24: error: unreported exception MalformedURLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            giveMeStream("http://foo.com").map(wrap(url -> new URL(url))),
                                                           ^
AppDemo.java:25: error: unreported exception MalformedURLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            giveMeStream("http://bar.com").map(wrap(url -> new URL(url))));
                                                           ^
3 errors
```

Comment: You forgot to include the actual error?

Comment: Hi I posted code from wrong file how can I update the code ?

Comment: @Fazal click the edit at the bottom of the post (below the tags)

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam Thanks, I have edited the code, added compilation error.

Comment: If you change `Stream.concat(` to `Stream.<URL>concat(` then the next two lines compile correctly. Odd.

Comment: prefer using constructor reference `URL::new`

Comment: Seems to be a type inference issue. Using `(String url) -> new URL(url)` solves it. As a side note, instead of `Arrays.stream(new String[]{s})`, you can use `Stream.of(s)`, which renders the `giveMeStream` method obsolete. So you could just use `Stream.of("http://foo.com", "http://bar.com").map(wrap(URL::new)) …`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because slight updates to the spec say so, probably. Does it matter? It's not going to work like this.

There is no real purpose to turning the exception thrown into a parameterized type here. Also, youll make quite the chain of `RuntimeException` with this code. Try this, instead:

```
static <T, R> Function<T, R> wrap(FunException<T, R> fn) {
    return t -> {
        try {
            return fn.apply(t);
        } catch (Error | RuntimeException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Checked exception in lambda", throwable);
        }
    };
}

interface FunException<T, R> {
    R apply(T t) throws Throwable;
}
```

and now it'll compile fine.

TO THE READER: Don't do this. The correct way to deal with java's rules such as checked exceptions is to deal with them. Using hacks to get around the essence of a language just means your code is non-idiomatic (others who read your code won't get it, and you'll have a hard time reading the code of others. That's bad), tends to interop with other libraries in a bad way, and various features that are supposed to help, now hurt (example: Here you get a LOT of causal exception chains which make the reading of your logs and exception traces more difficult than is needed). Also, being 'off the beaten path' this far leads to fun times such as code that used to compile no longer compiling.

Comment: Is there a real use for having multiple catch blocks here? Throwable wrapper will always be called! Just asking

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thanks for the help. I totally agree with the advice in handling checked exceptions.

Comment: I think you may have missed @Fazal's point. We ask for minimal reproducible example, and that's what Fazal has given us. He is not asking how to do something, he's asking why the same exact code compiles in some places and not in others.

Comment: Funny that the author of @SneakyThrows advises agains "using hacks to get around the essence of a language" ;-)

Comment: Adding the new catch clause is of no interest, Throwable will catch everything...

Comment: This solution is as idiomatic as [`UncheckedIOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html), which was created specifically to deal with the checked `IOException` in the `Stream` API, by wrapping it…

Comment: @Kris and Jean-Baptiste Yunes of course that extra clause is useful: Now, any exception that can just be thrown is thrown. The other one will wrap them. With enough applications of lambdas, any exception will be 8-deep inside a chain of RuntimeExceptions.

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath Different kinds of hacks. I'd say that a hack that 'infects' your actual project and cannot easily be eliminated, such as going a bit too deep down the 'wrap'+lambda rabbit hole, are a bad idea. Having an easily reversible option that doesn't is a better proposition. Also, sneakythrows' purpose is to get around exceptions that are effectively 'erroneously checked', whereas this wrap thing is a more blanket 'I want to do checked exceptions things of all stripes in lambdas'. But, touché :)